# Need explanation on expression transformation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Very based question regarding expression transformation.

$$\log p_i \leq \log i + 2 \log\log i $$
$$ p_i \leq i(\log i)^2$$

I am not getting this transformation. 
So from what I try:

$$\log p_i \leq \log (2i \log\log i) $$
$$ p_i \leq 2i \log\log i$$
$$ p_i \leq 2i \log^2 i$$
$$ p_i \leq \log^2 i^{2i}$$

And I am stuck...

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$log(p_i)\leq log(i)+2\log(log(i))$$
$$log(p_i)\leq log(i)+\log(log(i)^2)$$
$$log(p_i)\leq \log(i\log(i)^2)$$
$$p_i\leq i\log(i)^2$$

Here the second inequality follows since $a\log(b)=\log(b^a)$, and the third since $\log(a)+\log(b)=\log(ab)$. The last inequality holds since th logarithm is an increasing function.